Where can I learn graphic design?
I'm searching for a comprehensive graphic design course. Although I'm not a complete beginner, I want to start from scratch and build a portfolio. Ideally the course (or courses) should cover all the essentials required for entry-level or intern positions. After a disappointing experience with a UX/UI course, I'm only interested in finding a valuable resource. I considered Udemy but found the projects and final outcomes not quite to my liking. However if I'm underestimating Udemy, please let me know. Any recommendations for excellent sources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Look for a university in your country. I would consider a graduate from one of them as entry-level, and expect them to know the essentials. There is probably 1 in a thousand that has so much talent without a degree, that I would encourage him to get a degree so he does not waste his potential. So probably that case would not be entry-level. If has experience and talent, that would not be entry-level.

Just for the sake of clarity -- are you asking about courses focused on software? Or courses focused on things like art history, design theory, the psychology of marketing? Places like Udemy, from what I can tell, are pretty much all about how to use software (which isn't really design).

@Scott Hey, thanks for the question. I think this is a very important point, that's why I am looking for something in between maybe. More like theory + software.

I don't think such a thing exists outside formal education. Most non-institutional courses are overly focused on software. Basically, they are all kind of like Udemy. If you want more you need to look into local universities, Art school, colleges, or Community Colleges (not sure of Com. colleges exist outside US).

If you're not a complete beginner, interacting with clients and getting paid for work is the best learning experience.
Otherwise, learning how to use the apps, past and present design styles, typography, grids, tools, you can learn all that from anything like books, courses, blogs, youtube or going to an actual design school.

Tips and resources for beginning designers
How do I learn to be creative?
What is the single most influential book every designer should read?


Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the design schools in my country are not very reliable that's why I am looking for alternatives. I am not a complete beginner since I know how to use some tools, but I wouldn't want to work with clients until I feel confident. Thanks for the links again!
